# Send Email in MERN app with Azure MFA enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, mern

I have Node/React app and using nodemailer for sending the emails using SMTP protocol which works fine but in client company's Azure environment, they have disabled the use of IMAP, POP3, SMTP authentication as these are legacy protocols and pose a security risk. Instead, they have in place Azure MFA modern authentication. Can you please guide us how to use this Azure MFA and then send the email in node after Azure authentication ?

Answer (score 1):

As SMTP auth is disabled in your client's environment there can be two possibilities to send mail from your application based on your requirement :

1. You can send mail directly from your application to Microsoft 365 or
   Office 365 using direct send (only used for internal organization)
2. You can  configure a connector to send mail using Microsoft 365 or
   Office 365 SMTP relay (can be used for external organization)

Please refer the below document for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365